# EclipseLink to Hibernate migration

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I'm trying to migrate enterprise application which was built for Glassfish3 + EclipseLink to JBoss7 + Hibernate.

When I'm trying to enable my application, the persistence unit does not start, throwing this exception

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."app-logic.ear/domain-jpa-ejb.jar#dataspace-PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."app-logic.ear/domain-jpa-ejb.jar#dataspace-PU": Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.fromAccessType(CacheConcurrencyStrategy.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.determineCacheConcurrencyStrategy(AnnotationBinder.java:1038)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.buildCacheMock(AnnotationBinder.java:1005)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.determineCacheSettings(AnnotationBinder.java:962)
```

Did anything similar happened to you? Seems weird to me, that NullPointerException is thrown. I tried to inspect whats' on the line 52 in CacheConcurrencyStrategy, but it doesn't seem able to throw such exception.

Note that I'm not using any persistence-provider specific annotations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that some update of library fixed this issue. Anyway if anyone will have similar problem, please let me know. I'm interested where the problem really was.

Answer (score 0):

A previous bug in hibernate 4.1 has been fixed. Nevertheless, I had similar problem on 4.2, JBoss7.1 / maybe it was same as yours.

In persistence.xml, I have set

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

AND NEED specify

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />
```

otherwise, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.fromAccessType(CacheConcurrencyStrategy.java:52)
```

I hope this may help anybody else ?!